# Malicious requests from search.live.com hitting production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been checking my production.log today and there's a number of requests hitting my site that appear to be malicious, but I'm confused as to how they're even getting to us.

For example:

Processing PublicController#unknown_request (for 217.23.4.13 at 2009-11-09 09:15:52) [GET]
  Parameters: {"anything"=>["results.aspx"], "action"=>"unknown_request", "first"=>"200", "controller"=>"public", "q"=>"\"bbs/cbbs.cgi?\" intitle:\"Book\" intext:\"2008\" site:.uz ", "count"=>"200", "FORM"=>"PERE"}
Completed in 16ms (View: 12, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http : // search . live .com /results.aspx?q=%22bbs/cbbs.cgi%3F%22%20intitle%3A%22Book%22%20intext%3A%222008%22%20site%3A.uz%20&count=200&first=200&FORM=PERE]

These are happening every 30 seconds or so. Obviously, PublicController/Unknown_request is my controller/action 404 error.

The access log shows these requests as:

217.23.4.13 - - [09/Nov/2009:09:57:25 +1000] "GET http://search.live.com/results.aspx?q=%22en-gb.html%22%20intitle%3A%22Home%22%20intext%3A%222006%22%20site%3A.mn%20&count=200&first=400&FORM=PERE HTTP/1.1" 200 3626 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; FreeBSD i386; en-US; rv:1.1$

How are these requests even hitting my site? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be the same problem you're having: http://penguinpetes.com/b2evo/index.php?p=567&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

Basically, live/bing are doing some sort of testing that involves going to your site looking like someone searched something completely irrelevant to the content you have.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  The IPs resolve to the Netherlands, and I've seen words like teen, babe and v$gina show up!